# My argparse const=open() option always creates empty files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am a student and for practice am creating a little program that converts .fastq to .fasta files (so it deletes some lines, basically).

I am trying to implement the typical user input of an input file and an output file with the argparse library. For the output, I am trying to have three scenarios:

1. user puts -o outputfilename.fasta to create an outfile with custom name
2. user puts no argument, then it prints output in stdout
3. user puts -o with no followup, then it should create a file by itself with the name from input .fasta.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import re           
import sys          
                
c=1
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--input", "-i", required=True, dest="inputfile", type=argparse.FileType("r"))
parser.add_argument("--output", "-o", dest="outfilename", type=argparse.FileType("w"), nargs="?", default=sys.stdout, const=open('{}.fasta'.format(sys.argv[2]), "w" ))

args = parser.parse_args()

for line in args.inputfile:
        if c==1:
            line=re.sub ("[@]", ">", line)
            args.outfilename.write (line)
            c=c+1
        elif c==2:
            args.outfilename.write (line)   
            c=c+1
        elif c==3:
            c=c+1
        else:
            c=1
```

I am struggling with the third option, because the way my code is now, it always creates the extra file, but empty. So basically, it always runs my const= option, even though according to the manual, it shouldn't.

(just to be clear: I type -o outfilename.fasta and it produces the file plus an empty one from the input name. I type no argument and it prints it in my commandline and produces the empty inputname file. I type -o and it produces the inputfilename.fasta file with the correct lines in it)

> *nargs='?'. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the value from default will be produced. Note that for optional arguments, there is an additional case - the option string is present but not followed by a command-line argument. In this case the value from const will be produced.*

Because I thought the open command might be problematic, I tried it with

```
parser.add_argument("--output", "-o", dest="outfilename", type=argparse.FileType("w"), nargs="?", default=sys.stdout, const=argparse.FileType('{}.fasta'.format(sys.argv[2]), "w" ))
```

(I just wanted another way to write a file without using open)
and weirdly enough it only gave me this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./fastqtofastaEXPANDED.py", line 19, in 
args.outfilename.write (line)
AttributeError: 'FileType' object has no attribute 'write'

when I used -o argument. So that would tell me the opposite, that it does indeed only use the const option when I type -o, and not in the other cases (since the other ones worked fine, without extra files and without error messages).
I am confused as to why with the open parameter it seems to use const all the time....

I feel like a solution to my problem might be in the action classes, but I couldn't wrap my head around that yet. I would be no problem if the const just worked the way the manual says :D or is it error in the open, after all?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Since the const= probably won't work the way I wanted, I've created this work-around.
Basically just said that if the value is None, it will open a new file with name from the first input, minus suffix, plus new suffix.
If someone has a better solution, I am still open to change it :)

```
parser.add_argument("--output", "-o", dest="outfilename", type=argparse.FileType("w"), nargs="?", default=sys.stdout)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.outfilename==None:
    i=sys.argv[2][:sys.argv[2].rfind(".")]
    args.outfilename=open("{}.fasta".format(i), "w")

#then all the line reading jazz...

if args.outfilename==None:
    args.outfilename.close()

#to close the file, if it was used.
```

Comment: You passed a keyword argument to `.add_argument()` named `const`, whose value was an opened file object.  That value is fully evaluated, thus resulting in the creation of the file, *unconditionally* - this happens before `.add_argument()` is even called.  Python can't retroactively decide to not have created the file, just because the function ends up not needing to use the `const` parameter.  I don't think you're going to get `const=` to work nicely with `type=FileType` - instead use string values for `-o`, and call `open()` on the file yourself.

Comment: @jasonharper I think I see what you mean. I thought the const= and default= were kind of like if and elif and else. so that depending on what the input is, it goes to use either/or. but I guess the const= parameter, since it is seen as a "constant", is always created, just not always used.

I've done a work-around for it then. It might not be smooth, but my brain wasn't ready for more at the moment haha. I've put an edit in. 
It'd still be cool if someone had a shorter solution :)

Comment: Python evaluates all arguments before passing them to the function.  The `type` argument is supposed to be a function (callable),  `argparse.FileType(..)` creates such a function.  `FileType` is a class, that returns an instance with a `__call__` method; it describes itself as a `factory`.  In short, `argparse` is pure python code, so all the python syntax and evaluations apply.

Comment: If a `default` is a string, it will be passed through the `type` function at the end, if needed.  That is, `type(default)` is deferred.  The same is true for a `const` parameter.  If it is a string, it is passed through `type` if it is used.   So `const='fasta2' will conditionally make that file.   You might even be able to make the string depend on `sys.argv[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

With this script:

```
import argparse, sys
# testing the use of `sys.argv` to create a filename (so-so idea)
if sys.argv[1:]:
    constname = f'foobar{sys.argv[1]}.txt'
else:
    constname = 'foobar1.txt'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
a2 = parser.add_argument('number', type=int)
a1 = parser.add_argument('-o','--output', nargs='?', default='foobar0.txt', 
                          const=constname, type=argparse.FileType('w'))
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Sample runs:

```
1253:~/mypy$ rm foobar*
1253:~/mypy$ python3 stack63357111.py
usage: stack63357111.py [-h] [-o [OUTPUT]] number
stack63357111.py: error: the following arguments are required: number
1253:~/mypy$ ls foobar*
foobar0.txt
```

Even though `argparse` issues an error and quits, it creates the `default` file.  That's because the `output` default is processed before the `required` check.  Trying to create a `const` value based on some number in `sys.argv` is clumsy, and error prone.

```
1253:~/mypy$ python3 stack63357111.py 2
Namespace(number=2, output=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='foobar0.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>)
1254:~/mypy$ ls foobar*
foobar0.txt
```

`argparse` creates the default and leaves it open for you to use.

```
1254:~/mypy$ python3 stack63357111.py 2 -o
Namespace(number=2, output=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='foobar2.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>)
1254:~/mypy$ ls foobar*
foobar0.txt  foobar2.txt
```

`argparse` creates the `const` based on that `number` positional

```
1254:~/mypy$ python3 stack63357111.py 2 -o foobar3.txt
Namespace(number=2, output=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='foobar3.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>)
1254:~/mypy$ ls foobar*
foobar0.txt  foobar2.txt  foobar3.txt
```

Making a file with the user provided name.

Overall I think it's better to keep the use of `FileType` simple, and handle special cases after parsing.  There's no virtue in doing everything in the parser.  Its primary job is to determine what the user wants; your own code does the execution.